# How to use preg_replace to translate Japanese to English from a remote website

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, preg-replace, str-replace

I'm trying to write a PHP script to translate Japanese cooking recipes from Japanese to English.  This is pet project and doesn't have to be perfect.  My tactic is..

1. Fetch the website contents using file_get_contents
2. Replacing some Japanese with English (mostly names of ingredients)
3. Write the results to an HTML file

I'm running this PHP script from the command line:

```
<?php

    // Get contents of Japanese cooking website
    $url = 'http://recipe.igamono.jp/?eid=1077379';
    $context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header' => 'Accept-Charset: UTF-8, *;q=0')));
    $html = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    // Replace stuff
    $html = preg_replace('/right/s', 'foobar', $html); // works
    $html = preg_replace('/の/s', 'shazam!!', $html); // doesn't work

    // Write output to a file
    file_put_contents('output.html', $html);

?>
```

I'm using Sublime Text to edit the file (translate.php), and I've made sure to save the file using: File / Save with Encoding / UTF-8

When I run the script, everything works except for the replacement of の. No substitutions of の occur.

However, this ***does*** work:

```
<?php
    $html = "one の two の";
    $html = preg_replace('/の/s', 'shazam!!', $html);

    file_put_contents('output.html', $html);
?>
```

The output is:

> one shazam!! two shazam!!

Any suggestions?  I know that this is a character encoding issue, but I just can't seem to get it working.

**UPDATE:**

Here's a modified version that tests the UTF-8 encoding on the $html variable:

```
<?php
    // Get contents of Japanese cooking website
    $url = 'http://recipe.igamono.jp/?eid=1077379';
    $context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header' => 'Accept-Charset: UTF-8, *;q=0')));
    $html = file_get_contents($url, FILE_TEXT, $context);

    if(mb_detect_encoding($html, 'UTF-8')) print("Yep, UTF-8 it is.\n");
    if(! mb_detect_encoding($html, 'UTF-8', true)) print("Well, on second thought.. maybe not!\n");

?>
```

The output is:

> Yep, UTF-8 it is.
>
> Well, on second thought.. maybe not!

**MY SOLUTION**

Here's one solution that I came up with:

```
<?php
    // Get contents of Japanese cooking website
    $url = 'http://recipe.igamono.jp/?eid=1077379';
    $html = file_get_contents($url);

    // Convert HTML to UTF-8 from Japanese
    $html = mb_convert_encoding($html, "UTF-8", "EUC-JP");

    // Replace stuff
    $html = preg_replace('/right/s', 'foobar', $html);
    $html = preg_replace('/の/s', 'shazam!!', $html);

    // Convert HTML back to Japanese character encoding
    $html = mb_convert_encoding($html, "EUC-JP", "UTF-8");

    // Write HTML to a file
    file_put_contents('output.html', $html);
?>
```

Comment: That's it! Happy it's resolved..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion:

```
    $html = preg_replace('/[\x{306E}]/u', 'shazam!!', $html);
```

**UPDATE:**
Turns out the page you're loading is not UTF-8, but EUC-JP. Doing:

```
<?php

// Get contents of Japanese cooking website
$url = 'http://recipe.igamono.jp/?eid=1077379';
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('header' => 'Accept-Charset: EUC-JP, *;q=0')));
$html = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

// Replace stuff
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, "UTF-8", "EUC-JP");
$html = preg_replace('/right/s', 'foobar', $html); // works
$html = preg_replace('/の/s', 'shazam!!', $html); // doesn't work

// Write output to a file
file_put_contents('output.html', $html);
?>
```

I get "shazam!!"

[image: shazam]

Comment: If I use /su, my output file is blank.  If I use just /s, I get: Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: character value in \x{} or \o{} is too large at offset 8.  Maybe this is a good idea, but perhaps my $html is not UTF-8?

Comment: Solved it.. But: I edited Mvorisek's answer by mistake instead of my own. Now it needs to be "peer reviewed"... Problem is the Japanese page isn't UTF-8 but EUC-JP and needs to be converted to UTF-8 first in order for の to be shazammed..

Comment: I also solved it.  I'll post my solution as an edit to my question, but I'll accept yours if it also works.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$html = preg_replace('/の/su', 'shazam!!', $html);` (with /u UTF-8 modifier).

**UPDATE:**

When using /u modifier, the input text ($html here) MUST BE UTF-8 valid, otherwise nothing will be replaced at all. The input text encoding can be checked by `mb_check_encoding($string, 'UTF-8')`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  mb_detect_encoding($html, 'UTF-8') is true, but the "strict" version, mb_detect_encoding($html, 'UTF-8', true), is false.  Also, if I needed the /u modifier, my second example should have failed too, right?  When I add the /u modifier, the output is blank.  Darn!